# How do I make steel in cycles using 2.5 as the IOR?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

How do I make steel in cycles using 2.5 as the IOR?
2.5 is the listed PBS IOR of steel but I have no idea how to make a great node metal shader in cycles using this info.
Thanks!
Douglas E Knapp

Comment: The only places IOR is really used is in the Glass shader I think, for transparent materials. IDK how to implement it for purely surface materials, if indeed that possibility exists.

Answer (score 1):

The FRESNEL node connected to a the FACTOR input of a MIX node which has for example a DIFFUSE and GLOSSY input will change the reflections depending on the angle that light strikes it.

The FRESNEL node has a panel for the IOR

http://www.chocofur.com/6-shadersamptextures.html

Comment: I should have known that . . . you have a better memory :)

Comment: That sounds good and I tried it but at 2.5 it give a really bad output. Why?